# How to find a value, in which Range that it lies without using Between or Comparison operator in expression

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a Table

```
Low     High      Item
0        45        A
45.01    75.24     B
75.24    108.00    C
108..01  122.00    D
```

Example : If My input is `30` should find in which range does it lies and return the corresponding Item i.e, `A` ( without using Between or Comparison operator in expression)

Comment: Is this a homework question?  It sounds pretty arbitrary if it's not

Comment: What range does 75.24 fall in?  B or C?  Is the overlap intentional?

Comment: @ Aaron, Sorry 75.24 falls in B and 75.25 to 108.00 is C.

Comment: @ Rob - Pls dont consider this as arbitrary one. I think im clear with my query .!! I just wanted to know is there any way to know a value in which range it lies without using comparison operators like checking Low>0 High<45.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the ranges are non-overlapping:

```
select top 1 t.*
from table t
order by (@input - low)*(high - @input) desc;
```

The expression `(@input - low)*(high - @input)` should be positive only for values in the range.  The descending sort will put them first.

This is using SQL Server syntax.  Other databases might use `limit` or something else.

Comment: i have a dataset , i need to write an expression in vb.net

Comment: need the logic either in vb or C#  .!!

Answer (score 0):

Why not  this

**Qyery 1 :**

```
Select * 
From Table1 
Where 30 > Low AND 30 < High
```

## [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5588a/1)

**Qyery 2 :**

```
Select * 
From Table1 
Where 50.02 Between Low and high
```

## [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5588a/6)

**Query 3 :**

```
select t.*
from table1 t
where high - 99.9 > 0 and Low - 99.99 < 0
```

## [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b3e28/1)

Hope this help you

Comment: Sorry i dont want to use these comparison operators